# Create a query in Access to show last entry for a serial number

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

So I have a database that tracks location changes for assets. Every time the form is filled out it automatically makes a date and time stamp for every location change.

Columns look like this.

```
[Serial Number][New Location][Date][Time]
```

Example would be"

```
[DE1234567][Warehouse][5/7/2014][10:02PM]
```

What I want to do now is create a query that will show me all the assets that are currently in these locations.

```
[Location1][serial1][Date/Time]
[Location1][serial2][Date/Time]
[Location1][serial5][Date/Time]
[Location1][serial7][Date/Time]
[Location2][serial4][Date/Time]
[Location2][serial6][Date/Time]
[Location2][serial8][Date/Time]
[Location2][serial9][Date/Time]
```

Or Something along those lines.

What I need to do is get the query to find the last dated entry for each serial number and only show that entry and ignoring anything older. I can't delete older ones because i need the history every asset.

P.s. The reason I don't use any old asset tracking software is because this in the future will also be used to track in house repairs of these assets and answering this question will also help me do that later.

Thanks

~~~~Added 12:35AM 5/8/2014~~~~

Tried this code from answer by "GeoB". Still shows same data just sorted.

```
SELECT [Cassette Status History].[New Location], [Cassette Status History].[Serial Number], Max([Cassette Status History].[Date/Time]) AS [Last Date/Time]
FROM [Cassette Status History]
GROUP BY [Cassette Status History].[New Location], [Cassette Status History].[Serial Number];
```

This showed all entries just but sorted, and grouped. I want this query to hide all entries from the same serial number but the one with the latest date.

~~~~Added 9:29PM 5/8/2014~~~~

I Tried this code as per Answer by "Heinzi"

```
SELECT [Cassette Status History].[New Location], [Cassette Status History].[Serial Number], [Cassette Status History].[Date/Time]
  FROM [Cassette Status History]
 WHERE [Cassette Status History].[Date/Time] = (SELECT MAX([Cassette Status History].[Date/Time])
                          FROM [Cassette Status History]
                         WHERE [Cassette Status History].[Serial Number] = [Cassette Status History].[Serial Number])
```

This now only shows the very last entry entered into that table.

Thanks again everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You want all the records where `Date/Time` are the *highest* value for this serial number. So let's translate that directly to SQL:

```
SELECT A.[New Location], A.[Serial Number], A.[Date/Time]
  FROM [Cassette Status History] A
 WHERE A.[Date/Time] = (SELECT MAX(B.[Date/Time])
                          FROM [Cassette Status History] B
                         WHERE A.[Serial Number] = B.[Serial Number])
```

*Alternatively*, if you want to use the query designer, you can spit the problem into smaller pieces:

- Create a Query `LastMovements`, which contains only `Serial Number` and the maximum `Date/Time` for that serial number. This is similar to the query you already have, just without the location.
- Then create a new query that joins `LastMovement` to `Cassette Status History` to add the location.

Comment: In your SQL what in B refering to? I Only have 1 table set up. Is it the query itself?

Comment: `MyTable A`, which would be `[Casette Status History] A` in your case (I updated my answer), means: Take table `MyTable`, and let it henceforth be known as `A`. This allows us to select the same table twice, with A referring to your table in the outer SQL and B to the same table in the inner SQL.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been doing this with your second approach for years - but always wanted to know how to combine everything into one query.  Your 1st solution shows me how to do that.

Comment: OK so I pretty much copied your method and filled in the blanks, and it still doesn't work. Now it only shows the very last entry... I added the code I used to the original question if you want to see if I made any mistakes.

Comment: I don't want 2 queries but I am going to try your second method for now Thanks;)

Comment: @Ajster1989: The aliases (`A` and `B`) are necessary for this to work! Otherwise, the inner WHERE clause does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new query design and switch to SQL View.  Copy in the following:

```
SELECT yourtable.[New Location], yourtable.[Serial Number], Max([yourtable.Date]+[yourtable.Time]) AS Timestamp
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY tTest.[New Location], tTest.[Serial Number];
```

Date and Time fields are added to make a complete timestamp.

In Design View you'll see how the query could be built.

[note: the above assumes that ACC2013 is substantially similar to ACC2010]

Comment: After seeing this I kind of understand better, but unfortunately it didn't work. I put the same serial number in my database 2 times, once in the Location "Ready for Field" and 20min. later in the location "In Field" after setting it up the way you explained it showed both entries.

Comment: What happens if you rename the date and time fields, since those field names are reserved words?

Comment: well as I'm new to access and just learning this I later combined the date time fields together using the "Now()" command to make an automated timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Took me hours of playing with it, but hey at least I'm smarter now because of it.

Here is the code I am using.

```
SELECT First([Cassette Status History].[New Location]) AS [FirstOfNew Location], [Cassette Status History].[Serial Number], Max([Cassette Status History].[Date/Time]) AS [MaxOfDate/Time]
FROM [Cassette Status History]
GROUP BY [Cassette Status History].[Serial Number]
ORDER BY First([Cassette Status History].[New Location]);
```

I did this in design view by first making the table that only shows Serial Numbers with Total set to "Group By" and Date/Time set to "Max" then after that I added in the New Location Field as just extra info using totals set to "First" and sorted ascending.

Now that I'm looking at it it seems really simple....

Thanks everyone for all your help, I learned alot!